# How to use command \chapter with customised looks in report

Tags: packages, chapters, syntax

i'm new to latex. I met recently a problem at using \chapter from `report` class. When I use the `\chapter{Introduction}`, it will turn out as the following[image].

but I want to have the form like **1 Introdution** How can I remove the Chapter 1 and change into the form **1 Introduction**. Thank you in advance

Comment: do you need chapters, you could use `article` class and use `\section` which is what most people start with and has the layout you want

Comment: You can do that with `titlesec` , adding in the preamble `\ titleformat{\chapter}{\normalfont\bfseries}{\huge\thechapter}{0.5em}{\Huge}`.